# Office resource scheduling/tracking software

Tags: asset-management

I'm looking for tracking software for our office resources (projectors, hotspots, laptops, etc).  These items aren't assigned to anyone in particular, but rather "checked in" and "checked out" for various timeframes.

**Requirements:**

- Free
- Scheduling capability
- Request system (ie I would like a projector from 7/1 to 7/8)
- Ability to approve/deny request
- Resource availability check during reservation

**Nice to Haves:**

- Active Directory Integration
- Web Based
- Wordpress Integration
- Email notification to admin on request
- Email notification to requester when item is due back

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: jmgardn2, welcome to Server Fault - but shopping questions are off-topic here, as they are across the entire [SE] network, so please don't take it personally if this question gets closed.  See our [FAQ], and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ , for further details.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @MadHatter, I thought this would have been more of a solution recommendation instead of a shopping request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Exchange 2010's equipment mailboxes? I was looking into that a while ago, but never got around to actually setting anything up with it.

Comment: Hmmm, haven't seen that yet.  Unfortunately we are running 2007 right now (slated to upgrade to Exchange 2013 Q1 next year).  I'll look into it and see if it fits our needs and is something we could wait for.  Thanks!

Comment: It's in Exchange 2007 as well @jmgardn2 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124925%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Comment: I just noticed that as I was exploring it more.  Thanks again, and I will investigate to see if it fits our needs!